# how to use git rebase more effectively in the following scenario

Tags: git, git-rebase

My workflow is as follows: there is a main branch called develop, which should always have passing tests. When working on a feature, I create a new branch to work on this ticket with:

```
git checkout -b feature_name
```

Then create a remote tracking branch for it with:

```
git push -u origin feature_name
```

Then I keep committing on this branch, and sometimes I merge from develop with this:

```
git checkout develop; git pull; git checkout feature_branch; git merge develop
```

so that the branch keeps getting updated from the develop branch.

When I am done, I merge this branch into develop and push:

```
git checkout develop; git pull; git merge feature_branch; git push
```

This uses the git pull strategy for merging. But when I do the above, sometimes my commits show on top, sometimes somewhere else, sometimes interspersed, so it is hard to see what I did. I want to know how to use rebase in the above scanario so that the history of my commits shows on top.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `git merge develop` to `git rebase develop`.

Answer (score 1):

In the third line change your workflow to

`git rebase origin/develop`

and at the end

`git checkout develop; git pull; git rebase feature_branch; git push;`

A note: rebase will only work without problems if you don't rebase remote commits. You don't want to change remote history, do you?

Comment: I dont use rebase at all, so I dont rebase remote commits!

Comment: So, according to your answer, in my workflow, i replace all git-merge commands with git-rebase commands, and thats it?

Comment: Make a copy of your project and try these commands without `git push`. In this case you won't mess up your remote. (I always do this if I am trying out new - maybe destructive - features.) If you rebase, your history will be cleaner as there will be no Merge commits. And if you rebase origin then you don't have to checkout/pull/checkout/merge.